# How do I program an HTML page to update text imported from a text file on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm been having a lot of trouble figuring out a way to update the text in a section without having to reload the page. What I would like the code to do is update the text and a picture in a section (id="section2" below) when you click on one of the tabs.

What I want the page to do when you click on one of the tabs is to load text (and in the future a .jpg too) from a local .txt file. As of right now, the changeText function updates the text but only when you manually type in the text.

From my code below this works:

$('#section-text').html("test of text1");

but what I would like to do would be to load text in from a .txt file called "text1.txt"

$('#section-text').html("text1.txt");

I'm just starting to venture into the web programming so I have very little experience with JavaScript and JQuery so most of the stuff that I've shown below is trial and error from other sites. I've tried many other methods that I've found online but with very little success. So far this is the closest I've got to my ideal solution, but I find if I just copy and paste my text it loses formatting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. And if people have any suggestions on cleaning up some of the code it would also be very welcome.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <meta name="description" content="Test Page">

  <title>Test Page</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText(text){
      if (text == 'Example 1'){
        $('#section-text').html("test of text1");
        $('#section-pic').html("images/slide1.jpg");
      }
      if (text == 'Example 2'){
        $('#section-text').html("Change the text");
        $('#section-pic').html("images/slide2.jpg");
      }
      if (text == 'Example 3'){
        $('#section-text').html("Something new here");
        $('#section-pic').html("images/slide3.jpg");
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<div class="nav">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <ul>
    <li id="Example 1" onClick="changeText('Example 1');"><a>Example 1</a></li>
    <li id="Example 2" onClick="changeText('Example 2');"><a>Example 2</a></li>
    <li id="Example 3" onClick="changeText('Example 3');"><a>Example 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="section2" class="section2" align="center">
  <div id="section-text" class="section-text">
    <iframe src="des/text1.txt" style="overflow:hidden" width ="90%"; height="90%" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"></iframe> 
  </div>
  <div id="section-pic" class="section-pic">
    <span class="Centerer"></span>
    <img class="Centered" src="images/slide1.jpg" style="height:75%; width:90%"/>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
<style>
#header {
    background-color:#083266;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#section2 {
    width:100%;
    background-color:grey;
    padding-top:25px; 
    padding-bottom:25px; 
    height: 10cm; 
}
.section-text {
    width:60%;
    float:right;
    background-color:grey;
    padding-top:25px; 
    padding-bottom:25px; 
    text-align:center; 
} 
.section-pic {
    background-color:grey;
    width: 40%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;            
}
.Centerer {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.Centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width = 100px
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

</style>
```

AJAX attempt:

```
var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');

function loadFile() {
  reader.open('GET', 'text1.txt', true); 
  reader.onreadystatechange = displayContents;
  reader.send(null);
}

function displayContents() {
  if(reader.readyState==4) {
    var el = document.getElementById('page_content');
    el.innerHTML = reader.responseText;
  }
}
```

UPDATED - My Solution:

For those of you who run into the same problem as I did here is the solution I used. After a lot of searching and asking around I used the display option in my css file. So add the following to your css file:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
.unhidden { display: block; }
```

In my case I wanted to update some text and a picture with a click on each tab so I added the following script to my html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function unhide(divID,divID2) {
    $(".unhidden").each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("unhidden").addClass("hidden");
    });
    //change text 
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
      item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
    //change the images 
    var item = document.getElementById(divID2);
    if (item) {
      item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
  }
</script>
```

and here is the html script that I used:

```
<div class="section2" align="center">
  <div class="nav">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="javascript:unhide('Text1','Pic1');"> Example 1 </a></li>
      <li> <a href="javascript:unhide('Text2','Pic2');"> Example 2 </a></li>  
    </ul>  
  </div>  

  <div class="section-text">
    <div id="Text1" class="unhidden">
      <p> Text for Example 1 </p>
    </div>

    <div id="Text2" class="hidden">
      <p> Add your text here for Text 2 </p>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="section-pic">
    <div id="Pic1" class="unhidden">
      <span class="Centerer"></span>
      <img class="Centered" src="images/pic1.jpg" style="height:auto; width:auto"/>
    </div>

    <div id="Pic2" class="hidden">
      <span class="Centerer"></span>
      <img class="Centered" src="images/pic2.jpg" style="height:auto; width:auto"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Collin: Take a look at AJAX. It is what you need

Comment: @SandeepNayak I have tried AJAX, but I'm not just super familiar with the language.  I added my AJAX code above

Comment: Is your AJAX call success?

Comment: @SandeepNayak Honestly I don't even know what you are referring to. You're dealing with a real noob here. In my html code I've tried calling the loadFile() function like this: <li id="other1" onClick="loadFile()"> <a> Example 1 </a> </li>. Assuming that when I call the loadFile function it would pull up the "text1.txt" file as defined in the AJAX code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are bunch of things you would need to do. Following is a mockup that would help you understand how you can get the text from an external file. Since you are more looking at a configuration approach, I would recomment using an xml file instead of text ( but the choice is upto you ).

```
// Register click event for every 'li' element
$('li').click(function()
{
    var response = '';
    // grab the id of the 'li' for lookup
    var value = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://url/xml/test.xml", // Check for the structure below
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {            
              xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);             
              $(xmlDoc).find("id").each(function ()
              {
                  if($(this).text() == value)
                  {
                      $("#section-text").text($(this).find("title").text());
   $(".Centered").attr("src",$(this).find("title").text());                      
                  }
              });     
        }
    }); 
});

// structure of text file as xml

"<id>Example1<title>Text Of Example 1</title><img>images/example1Image.img</img></id><id>Example2<title>Text Of Example 2</title><img>images/example2Image.img</img></id>",
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gcfLso5s/4/

I would also recommend reading some articles on jquery and ajax to enhance the understanding on how it works.

Let me know if you got any questions.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. I was doing a bit more searching yesterday after I posted this and I think I found another one of my problems. Right now I'm just working from a local folder on my desktop instead of through a server. Apparently ajax will only work through a server. Anyway thanks for the post, once I switch to a local server with apache I'll let you know how it's working

Answer (score 0):

You can load a text file Via AJAX request and can set the text.where ever you want to.